# Can't find SalesForce Object

Tags: python, database, salesforce

I'm having some trouble with SalesForce, I've never used it before so I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong here.  I am using the [`simple_salesforce`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce) python module.  I have successfully pulled data from SalesForce standard objects, but this custom object is giving me trouble.  My query is

```
result = sf.query("Select Name from Call_Records__c")
```

which produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 15, in <module>
    result = sf.query("Select Name from Call_Records__c")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simple_salesforce/api.py", line 276, in query
    _exception_handler(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simple_salesforce/api.py", line 634, in _exception_handler
    raise exc_cls(result.url, result.status_code, name, response_content)
simple_salesforce.api.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://sandbox.company.com/services/data/v29.0/query/?q=Select+Name+from+Call_Records__c. Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'INVALID_TYPE', u'message': u"\nSelect Name from Call_Records__c\n                 ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:18\nsObject type 'Call_Records__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. 
Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."}]
```

I've tried it with and without the `__c` for both the table name and the field name, still can't figure this out.  Anything blatantly wrong?

Comment: Are you 100% sure `Call_Records` is the entity name of the custom object?

Comment: When I log onto SF, the tab says `Call Records`.  I assumed an underscore was the appropriate replacement for the space.

Comment: No , try finding the entity name of the custom object

Comment: IS the entity name on the `Call Records` tab anywhere?  Unfortunately, `result = sf.query("Select Name from CallRecords__c")` produced the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your result is Call_Records__c/CallRecords__c

Call_Records__c result = sf.query("Select Name from Call_Records__c")
 Or
CallRecords__c result  = sf.query("Select Name from CallRecords__c")

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
result = sf.query("Select Name from CallRecords__c")
```